# In Peskin & Schroeder's QFT book page 704, the definition of electric charge is opposite?

Tags: charge, field-theory, standard-model, quantum-electrodynamics, conventions

In Peskin's book Chapter 4, the QED Lagrangian in Eq.(4.3) which contains the interaction term $$\mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{int}}=-q\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi A_{\mu}\tag{4.3}.$$ From this Lagrangian we can derive the Maxwell equation $\partial_{\mu}F^{\mu\nu}=qj^{\nu}$ that is consistent with the classical electrodynamics.

While in Chapter 20, page 704 Eq.(20.79), the QED interaction term is just like $$\mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{int}}=q\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi A_{\mu}.$$ I think it would deduce an extra minus sign in Maxwell's equation so it's not consistent with the classical electrodynamics.

It seems that there's the relation $Q=-I_3-Y$ rather than $Q=I_3+Y$ on page 702. Should the Eq.(20.65) be $D_\mu=\partial_\mu+i g A_\mu^a T^a+i g^{\prime} Y B_\mu$ (or $|e|=-g\sin\theta_W=-g'\cos\theta_W$)?

---

I also find it in some notes may be right:

See Eq.(191) and Eq.(194-196): https://cds.cern.ch/record/984122/files/p1.pdf

See PDG page 180 Eq.(10.2): https://pdg.lbl.gov/2023/web/viewer.html?file=../download/Prog.Theor.Exp.Phys.2022.083C01.pdf

---

And I'm also little confused that some convention $D_\mu=\partial_\mu-i g A_\mu^a T^a+i g^{\prime} Y B_\mu$ can derive the relation $Q=I_3+Y$:

See page 376 Eq.(D.8) and Eq.(D.12) https://porthos.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/CTQFT/files/SM-FeynmanRules.pdf